# Is it possible to "reverse spread" with Object.assign()?

Tags: javascript

I know "reverse spread" might not be the proper description for it but I couldn't think of anything else.

I'm trying to remove a set of keys like `a` and `b`, from an object and store the rest in `rest`.

```
const { a, b, ...rest } = bunchOfKeysAndValues;
```

But I can't use spread operator.

Is it possible to achieve this with `Object.assign()` or in some other way?

Comment: Why can't you use the spread operator? There's nothing equivalent with `Object.assign()`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that *should* work https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-object-destructuring/#8-rest-object-after-destructuring

Comment: @Giuppox It works, but he says he's not allowed to use `...`

Comment: `But I can't use spread operator` -> why not, it works perfectly fine. It's called destructuring spread operator

Comment: @Naren because the project doesn't support spread operator. And no that isn't even remotely the same question.

Comment: you didn't mentioned that

Comment: @Naren I specifically mention `I can't use spread operator`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign()` to make a copy of the object, extract `a` and `b` from it, then remove them.

```
const rest = Object.assign({}, bunchOfKeysAndValues);
const {a, b} = rest;
delete rest.a;
delete rest.b;
```

Comment: Technically I don't even need to extract `a` and `b`

Comment: @vhflat That's not obvious from the question. Why do you *need* to remove `a` and `b` -- just ignore them in the rest of the code.

Comment: Because they are url query parameters and I want to remove them from the query.

Comment: That's a good reason :)